# JavaScript event only in current loop

Tags: javascript

I am using this script to enable and disable a submit button.

```
function validate_edit(selectVeld, nr) {
    // edit_naam
    if (document.getElementById('edit_naam[' + nr + ']').value.length < 5) {
        document.getElementById('div_edit_naam[' + nr + ']').className = "form-group has-warning has-feedback";
        document.getElementById('edit_naam_status[' + nr + ']').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('div_edit_naam[' + nr + ']').className = "form-group has-success has-feedback";
        document.getElementById('edit_naam_status[' + nr + ']').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback";
    }

    // Submit form
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('has-error').length > 0 || document.getElementsByClassName('has-warning').length > 0) {
        document.getElementById('submit_edit[' + nr + ']').disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('submit_edit[' + nr + ']').disabled = false;
    }
}
```

At the moment the submit button stays disabled because it is checking **all** class names and not only the class names in the current loop `['+nr+']`

How can I use `['+nr+']` while checking all class names in the current loop?
I do not want to check for `document.getElementById('div_edit_naam['+nr+']').className` because the validation can have up to 30 entries later on.

**Modification for trincot**

```
<button type="button" id="submit_edit_cnt['.$i.']" alt="'.$i.'" class="btn btn-primary edit_cnt">Bewerk</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validate_edit_cnt(selectVeld, nr)
{
    // Submit form
    if(document.querySelectorAll(".has-error[id$=\\[" + nr + "\\]]".length > 0 || document.querySelectorAll(".has-error[id$=\\[" + nr + "\\]]").length > 0) { document.getElementById('submit_edit_cnt['+nr+']').disabled = true; }
    else { document.getElementById('submit_edit_cnt['+nr+']').disabled = false; }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You would make your life a lot easier if you would abandon those [nr] id values and use classes (not numbered) instead, and wrap the items that belong together in an`div` element. Then you would limit the search to one such `div`'s descendants.

Answer (score 0):

The quick solution is to use `querySelectorAll` with a selector that will only capture `'[' + nr ']'` kind of elements.

Change:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('has-error').length > 0
```

to:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".has-error[id$=\\[" + nr + "\\]]").length > 0
```

#### Alternative design

You would make your life a lot easier if you would abandon those "[nr]" `id` values and use classes (not numbered) instead, and wrap the items that belong together in a `div` element. Then you would limit the search to one such `div`'s descendants.

Your HTML would look like something like below. Your actual HTML will be different, but this is just to point out where the `div` elements would be:

```
<form>
    <div>
        <input class="edit_naam form-group">
        <div class="div_edit_naam form-group"></div>
        <i class="edit_naam_status glyphicon form-control-feedback"></i>
        <button class="submit_edit">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="edit_naam form-group">
        <div class="div_edit_naam form-group"></div>
        <i class="edit_naam_status glyphicon form-control-feedback"></i>
        <button class="submit_edit">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <!--- etc, etc --->
</form>
```

And then the JavaScript would be more like below. Note how the DOM methods are not applied to `document`, but to `div`, which should become the argument to the function. You'll have to make sure the calls to it are adapted as well:

```
function validate_edit(div) {
    if (div.querySelector('.edit_naam').value.length < 5) {
        div.querySelector('.div_edit_naam').className = "div_edit_naam form-group has-warning has-feedback";
        div.querySelector('.edit_naam_status').className = "edit_naam_status glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback";
    } else {
        div.querySelector('.div_edit_naam').className = "div_edit_naam form-group has-success has-feedback";
        div.querySelector('.edit_naam_status').className = "edit_naam_status glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback";
    }

    div.querySelector('.submit_edit').disabled = 
        div.getElementsByClassName('has-error').length > 0 || div.getElementsByClassName('has-warning').length > 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried but on the result as expected, also no errors, see updated code, is this what you intended?

Comment: It is a bit difficult to guess what your HTML is. I saw your edit to the question, but the HTML only has the button, so I cannot test it. Could you provide HTML (inputs, form) that is needed to test the code?